# Easiest way to create a drawing canvas from within a C++ dll?

Tags: c++, user-interface, dll

The scenario is such: there's a program which loads my .dll/.so and calls a function from within it, possibly multiple times, each time expecting a different pointer to state. It uses the different states later in other calls into the dll. (It's a game AI, if you need context; each state is a AI player.)

What I want is a cross-platform way of creating a canvas window for each of those states (for visualization, debugging, etc.) I tried wx, but put it on hold, since it didn't appear to be easy at all. Are there any neat and small libraries that could do that or should I just go with WinAPI/X...?

Edit: Assume I cannot modify the host program.

Answer (score 1):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) is simpler to set up and drive than Wx, in my experience.  It's very cross platform too.

If you want to render some graphics from inside your DLL function without passing in any pointers to QImage or QWidget type things, probably the thing to do is use OpenGL.  Your DLL should just render to the current OpenGL context, which is global state and can just be setup outside the DLL (maybe using QGLWidget).

Update: Ah, I just noticed your edit re not being able to modify the host code.  This is a problem: any windows you create really need to be plugged into the host apps' event loop to work properly (e.g receive WM_PAINT when exposed/resized).  It's certainly possible in win32 for any old code (e.g your library) to just CreateWindow and draw its contents with GDI whenever it gets the chance, but the general window behaviour may be pretty broken (it may not work at all with Vista's double buffering; I haven't tried).  What I typically find easiest in this situation is simply to dump out image files and review then afterwards with image viewer of choice.  IMHO this is actually more useful for debugging than a "live" window because you can step backwards and forwards, zoom in, apply image-enhancement to highlight various issues, compare against previous runs for regression testing etc etc.  (If you really want the "live" views, write an image displayer which monitors a directory for new images, or streams them through a named pipe or something).

Comment: got an example how to make a window from inside a dll...?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want simple graphics, no widgets, SDL is very easy to use. If you do need complex controls, use Qt, as timday said.

Comment: didn't think of SDL, will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out [IUP](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/). It interfaces really well with Lua, and can be used entirely from an extension DLL there so it seems plausible that its C API could be used from a DLL plugged into something else.

IUP will get you a framework for opening a window containing the usual suspect kinds of controls, including a canvas. Its related library [CD](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/cd) will give you the usual drawing operations in that canvas.

Current releases are portable between Windows and *nix. The next major release will support MacOSX too.